# Adjust height of v-autocomplete (vuetify 3.0)

Tags: vuetify.js

I have been trying to adjust height of v-autocomplete but I am unable to adjust height.
I also tried adding height prop but it does not work. I also tried targeting the CSS class but that also does not work.

```
<style scoped>
.v-text-field .v-field {
  height: 40px !important;
}
</style>
```

Note: I want the style to be scoped.